In my eclipse RCP application i have defined a view which is next to problems view i want that custom view to be opened always and cannot be closed ,
need to remove close button of the view
i.e close button should be disabled/ removed how can i achieve this?
public class ReferencesView extends ViewPart implements ISearchResultViewPart, IPersistable {...}
i tried this  but it did't help
@Override
        public void init(IViewSite site) throws PartInitException {
            super.init(site);
            site.getActionBars().getToolBarManager().remove("org.eclipse.ui.file.close");
       }


Even if you can find a way to do this, don't. It's extremely user hostile. The user can reset the Perspective if they want.

I guess you are using Eclipse legacy.
Perhaps you can take a look at addStandaloneView() method in IPageLayout : view’s title can be hidden and no more close button. Can be used in Perspective createInitialLayout() method.
